# How to lookup Company_id that has the current User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I want to create a new `jobdescription` with `company_id` from the current user, but it doesn't work, I tried different ways and it's still not working.

So, I don't know how to build the query in my controller, if you can tell me where the issue is, that would be very kind of you. Thanks.

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150212182839) do

  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end



  create_table "jobdescriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "applyjobid"
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "department"
    t.text     "shift"
    t.string   "work_location"
    t.string   "position_supervisor"
    t.string   "supervisor_position_supervisor"
    t.decimal  "rate_pay"
    t.text     "benefits"
    t.text     "other_benefits"
    t.text     "job_summary"
    t.text     "job_duties"
    t.text     "tasks"
    t.text     "results"
    t.text     "responsibilities"
    t.text     "knowledge"
    t.text     "skills"
    t.text     "abilities"
    t.text     "physical_requirement"
    t.text     "work_envir_condition"
    t.text     "protective_clothing_and_devices_required"
    t.text     "tools_or_equipment_required"
    t.text     "qualifications"
    t.text     "education_and_training"
    t.text     "license_certification"
    t.text     "experience"
    t.text     "aptitudes_interests_temperament"
    t.text     "roles_relationships"
    t.text     "supervisory_responsibility"
    t.text     "advancement_promotion_opportunities"
    t.string   "internal_comment"
    t.string   "submited_by"
    t.string   "approved_by"
    t.string   "statut"
    t.date     "from_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "jobdescriptions", ["company_id"], name: "index_jobdescriptions_on_company_id"



  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "role_id"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.integer  "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name: "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"

end
```

Here is my **`JobdescriptionsController`**

```
class JobdescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'



  def new
    @jobdescription = Jobdescription.new
  end

  def create

    @jobdescription = current_user.company_id.jobdescriptions.create(jobdescription_params)
    redirect_to new_jobdescription_path
  end

  private

  def jobdescription_params
    params.require(:jobdescription).permit(:applyjobid, :job_title, :work_location, :rate_pay, :shift, )
  end

end
```

Model **`Jobdescription`**

```html
class Jobdescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company


end
```

Model **`Company`**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :jobdescriptions

end
```

Model **`User`**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  default_value_for :role_id, "1"
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :timesheets
    has_many :expenses
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `current_user.company_id` gives the integer value of the `company_id` for that user's company, when what you actually want is to get the company object instance itself. Then you can call `create` on that company instance.

So the assignment for `@jobdescription` in the `create` method would be:

`@jobdescription = current_user.company.jobdescriptions.create(jobdescription_params)`

Comment: Hi,  Draffensperger, thanks you very much for your quick reply, I did what you told me to do and it works perfectly. I used your method in rails console (it was working) but not in my controller, I'm so stupid. Thanks.